# compare text between specific line linux using diff

Tags: linux

I have two java files as text file and I want to compare the two text file only between specific set of lines. So how do i specify the line number to search for in the diff command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diff can't do that, but you can use `head` and `tail` to extract the lines, and use process substitution to use the results in diff:

```
diff <(head -n 100 file1.java | tail -n 20) <(head -n 120 file2.java | tail -n25)
```

Comment: thanks, I used the command,  diff <(head -n 40 BBMap.txt) <(head -n 40 mtuant1.txt) and it gave the output as below
1,40c1,40
But there is only one change between the two text, why am I getting line 1 to 40 be changed instead'

Comment: Without seeing the input it's hard to tell. Try using `diff -w` to ignore whitespace.